# C Sharp Pie Chart

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2005

Can anyone tell me how I can dynamically create a pie chart using graphics in C# in Visual Studio 2005?

Comment: WinForms, WPF, ASP.NET, ...?

Answer (score 3):

If you're using WinForms or ASP.NET and by chance targeting the .NET 3.5 I'd go with the free
[Microsoft Chart Controls for Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=142580)

Answer (score 2):

This [article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/julijanpiechart.aspx) will be a good place to start.
It is actually an entire library you just have to use it. The demo application and code will help with that.

Comment: This is awesome. I didn't look at the actual code, but I hope it's at least as nice as the application *looks*.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you're using WPF, as it has excellent support for pie charts...

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/piechart11122009230249PM/piechart.aspx